# Upgrading from windows 10 32 bit to windows 10 64 bit on asus t200ta

Tags: windows, asus-laptop

I recently bought a second-hand asus t200ta, with  a 64bit processor (which I confirmed) but only windows 10 32bit. I attempted to install 64 bit windows, but I encountered a number of errors. I installed the microsoft media creation tool and created an installation of 64 bit windows 10 successfully, but when I load the bios , where you should be able to change the boot order to boot from the second drive, where the installation of windows 10 64 bit is stored, there is only the option of 'Windows Boot Manager', even after I disable secure boot.

Comment: Just an FYI: You won't be doing an upgrade to change bit-ness. You'll have to do a clean install. The other question is why you wish to install the 64bit OS version. For a low-powered computer like this, the 32bit version of Windows will run better. There are also reports online that there are limitations in the BIOS that will not allow 64bit Windows 10 to be installed at all.

Comment: @music2myear I'm intrigued...why would a 32-bit OS perform better on low powered hardware?

Comment: Just read a few forum posts. Apparently the 64bit Win10 has "additional" security features such as required driver signing and other things which would basically make it run successfully on a narrower selection of hardware. I don't know if there's any performance penalty to running 64bit instructions because the CPU (and assumedly, the architecture as well) is 64bit, but the numbers the system has to handle would certainly be bigger. Some report the 2GB version of the t200a also only has a 32bit EUFI BIOS. On the Microsoft forums there were a handful of comments alluding to these issues.

Comment: The CPU is the Atom Z3795, likely: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/intel-atom-z3795-on-tablet-can-it-install-windows/315a322a-d96f-43d6-a4ff-d22d27cb2488 https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/intel-atom-z3795-windows-10-x64-pro-1809-no-audio/80db07a3-0d6e-43b3-a812-7bf2a5515be6 https://www.tenforums.com/installation-upgrade/40301-win10pro-64bits-not-possible-z3735f-w-ami-bios-9-failed-solutions.html

Comment: Actually, the 64 bit system works better than the 32 bit system, even for low powered devices, as the ram handling system is significantly improved, leading to an increase in overall performance. As for the UEFI, I was unaware that there were different versions for different versions of operating systems, as they exist on the pc before the OS does, and are, in fact, used to install the OS.

Comment: Devices that came with an Atom processor, did indeed have a 32-bit UEFI kernel and were incompatible with 64-bit versions of Windows.  There is also a very small performance penalty that does exist by running a 64-bit operating system on a device with less than 4 GB of memory.  There is a reason OEMs provide 32-bit versions of Windows on those types of devices, and it isn't connected to cost, since the costs are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a good idea to do this kind of modification to such an old
computer, but here is some advice.
Your biggest problem might be compatible drivers, if 64-bit drivers are not
available in Windows 10 for your devices.

The
[ASUS Transformer Book T200TA specifications](https://www.asus.com/us/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T200TA/specifications/)
indicate the CPU of
[Intel Bay Trail-T Quad Core Z3795](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/80267/intel-atom-processor-z3795-2m-cache-up-to-2-39-ghz.html)
which is said to be 64-bit capable.

I would start with updating the BIOS. To my surprise, I found a new and very recent
[BIOS update Version 212](https://www.asus.com/us/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T200TA/HelpDesk_BIOS/)
dating from 2019/06/10.
Be very careful to install a BIOS that fits your model exactly, or you risk bricking
the computer.

Once the latest BIOS is installed, you may try to upgrade the 32-bit Windows 10
from the 64-bit boot media that you have created.
Skip any demand for a Windows product key, since Windows will activate automatically
once it boots.

Before starting, I counsel using a product such as
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html)
to create a disk image on external media.
Create also the AOMEI Backupper boot media and test it, to see that it can while
booting see the external media disk with the image backup.